# Applescript : Get rid of space and return to line

Tags: variables, text, applescript

I can't get rid of the return to line and space in ma variable.

Here is my result at the moment

> 156545690
>
> 446654319
>
> 1047473595

and I would like to have :

> 156545690, 446654319, 1047473595

or even beter

> NUMBER : 156545690, NUMBER : 446654319, NUMBER : 1047473595

for get rid of the line here is my current script

```
set refnumberList to my getInputByClass2("sortable datanumber", 1)

to getInputByClass2(theClass) 
    tell application "Safari"
        set r to do JavaScript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;" in document 1
    end tell
    return strings of r 
    end getInputByClass2


set goodresult to items 2 thru -1 of refnumberList as string

set x to goodresult
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set y to (words of x)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
get y as string

set the clipboard to items 2 thru -1 of refnumberList as string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd recommend a repeat loop, it skips the empty lines and adds the `NUMBER` prefix. Then `text item delimiters` converts the list to a string.

```
set theText to "156545690

446654319

1047473595
"

set theResult to {}
repeat with aLine in (get paragraphs of theText)
    if length of aLine > 0 then
        set end of theResult to "NUMBER: " & contents of aLine
    end if
end repeat
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ", "}
set theResult to theResult as text
set text item delimiters to TID
theResult
```

Comment: set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ", "} is a very clever way to both save and change the text item delimiters in a single line, for easy restoration later. Great code @vadian.